# Category Block Random.phtml Display Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, category

How can I limit this block of code to display only 4 images from the category?

```
   <?$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()?>
   <?if(!$_productCollection->getSize()):?>
   <div class="note-msg">
   <?=$this->__('There are no products matching the selection.')?>
   </div>
   <?else:?>

   <div class="home-spot">
   <div class="box best-selling">
   <h3><?=$this->__('Accesssories')?></h3>
   <table cellspacing="0">
   <?$i=0;$j=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
   <?if ($i%2==0):?>
   <tr class="<?=($j++%2==0)?'even':'odd'?>">
   <?endif?>
   <td>                                           
   <a href="<?=$_product->getProductUrl()?>"><img src="<?=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(95, 95);?>" width="95" height="95" alt="<?=$this->htmlEscape($_product->getName())?>"/></a>
   <div class="product-description">
   <p><a href="<?=$_product->getProductUrl()?>" class="product-name"><?=$this->htmlEscape($_product->getName())?></a></p>
   <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" data-url="<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>" data-id="<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="btn btn-primary ajax-cart" ><i class="icon-cart"></i> <?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></a>
   </div>
   </td>
   <?if ($i%2!=0):?>
   </tr>
   <?endif?>
   <?$i++?>
   <?php endforeach?>
   </table>
   </div>
   </div>
   <?endif;?>
```

I'm displaying the results like this here in my category

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="22" products_count="4" columnCount="4" template="catalog/category/random.phtml"}}
```

however products_count="4" doesn't work. it just displays all images in that category. Is there some php I can used to control,

```
<?$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection()?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out but I'm not sure if it's the cleanest method. please advise as it works fine now with limitation. what I did was just add these lines of code to the top.

```
<?$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_productCollection->clear();
$_productCollection->setPageSize(3);
$_productCollection->load(); ?>
<?if(!$_productCollection->getSize()):?>
```

Now I can limit the number of products by adding a number to setPageSize(); However I'm not sure if I should be doing this or not. But it works great :) woo hoo!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="22" product_limit="4" columnCount="4" template="catalog/category/random.phtml"}}
```

Or:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
_productCollection->clear()
                    ->setPageSize(4)
                    ->load();
```